# MySQL, IF ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql, sql

I've simple question.

I'm trying to on duplicate key update supplier name and price if new price is lower than actual.
Query looks like this and don't work:

```
INSERT INTO import_queue (`IQ_ART_ID`,`IQ_PRICE`, `IQ_SUPPLIER`)
VALUES (2987621,'105.03', 'Supplier name')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IQ_SUPPLIER =
  IF(IQ_PRICE > 105.03, 'Supplier name', IQ_SUPPLIER) AND IQ_PRICE = IF(IQ_PRICE > 105.03,105.03, IQ_PRICE)
```

Thank you for any tips

Comment: can you post an error message as well?

Comment: This query seems to be valid.

Comment: Please define `don't work`.  If you get errors, please post them?  If you get unexpected results, please show the input data, the results of your query, and why they're not what you expected.

Comment: Thank you all for your advices, ONLY ERROR WAS <code>AND</code>.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `update` syntax seems a bit off.  You're missing the `SET` keyword, and multiple columns should be separated by `,` not `AND`:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        IQ_SUPPLIER = IF(IQ_PRICE > 105.03, 'Supplier name', IQ_SUPPLIER) 
        AND IQ_PRICE = IF(IQ_PRICE > 105.03,105.03, IQ_PRICE)
        ^^^
```

Try this instead:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
SET     IQ_SUPPLIER = IF(IQ_PRICE > 105.03, 'Supplier name', IQ_SUPPLIER) 
,       IQ_PRICE = IF(IQ_PRICE > 105.03, 105.03, IQ_PRICE)
```

Comment: Poster wants to use `INSERT [...] ON DUPLICATE KEY` (because of doing an `INSERT` when data does not exist)

Comment: Syntax is perfectly valid: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @rabudde: Yes, I'm talking about the `update` part of his `insert .. on duplicate key` statement.

Comment: @GermanRumm: Perhaps the `set` is optional, but I cannot imagine  `and` is allowed as a column separator

Comment: @Andomar, yes, `AND` is indeed wrong, multiple column assignments should be separated by commas

Comment: there was a problem with AND, but now there is a new problem when new price isn't lower IQ_SUPPLIER is set to 0 instead of no change